# Is there a way to ⎕NA import a dll exported C++ class in dyalog APL?

Tags: c++, class, dll, apl, dyalog

I have a .dll which exports a C++ class.  Is there some way to use ⎕NA to import this class into Dyalog APL?

I am looking at the DLL Export Viewer, and my class is exporting the way I expect. I have also written a C++ test application which imports the .dll and uses the class, and it functions the way I expect.

```
// built with default Visual Studio 2019 settings
class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass
{
public:
    void Func();
}
```

I need an example ⎕NA statement illustrating C++ classes imported into Dyalog APL from a .dll. Something like this:

```
'MyClass' ⎕NA 'what expression goes here'
mc←⎕NEW MyClass ⍝ or something similar
```

Comment: []NA is well documented, though it may take some iterations of development to get it working.  Consider also trying a plain C DLL first.  See also See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812963/cross-platforming-c-functions-to-apl/25181286#25181286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read "Name Association" description?
http://help.dyalog.com/latest/Content/Language/System%20Functions/na.htm
I guess it could help. There are some examples in the end of the article.